# Sending data over socket is incomplete

Tags: c#, image, sockets

For my project I am trying to take screenshot in client and sending them over socket to server. I used a loop to take screenshot until manually stop. But though taking screenshot is fine but after sending some images became only half of the main image and some images are full.
**Client:**
I am taking screenshot with this

```
bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
bmpScreenshot.Save(path + i + ".png");
ClientService.SendFile(path + i + ".png");
i++;
```

and the SendFile method is

```
public static void SendFile(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost");
                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], 5656);
                Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

                string filePath = "";

                fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
                while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
                {
                    filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                    fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                }

                byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
                if (fileNameByte.Length > 600 * 1024)
                {
                    showMsg = "File size is more than 600kb, please try with small file.";
                    return;
                }

                byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
                byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
                byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

                fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

                clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
                clientSock.Send(clientData);
                clientSock.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message == "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")
                    showMsg = "File Sending fail. Because server is not running.";
                else
                    showMsg = "File Sending fail." + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

**Server**

```
IPEndPoint ipEnd;
    Socket sock;
    public ServerService()
    {
        ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock.Bind(ipEnd);
    }

    public static string receivedPath;
    internal void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            sock.Listen(100);

            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + "/" + fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMsg = "Something is wrong." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Receive` is only guaranteed to (one of):

- return at least 1 byte
- signal an EOF (non-positive bytes)
- signal an error

It is not sufficient to call `Receive` once. You need to call it *in a loop*, until either:

- you have read all the data you want
- you get an EOF
- you get an error

In your case, I suggest you want to:

- read exactly 4 bytes (which can require a loop) to get the name length, `n`
- then read exactly `n` bytes to read the name
- then read until you get an EOF (a non-positive result from `Receive`)

Also: you probably want to use a `Stream`-based API for the file access (both read and write) rather than `File.ReadAllBytes` or `BinaryWriter`.

Reading *exactly* `n` bytes is a case of something like:

```
public void ReceiveExactly(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int read;
    while(count > 0 && (read = socket.Receive(buffer, offset, count,
        SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
    {
        offset += read;
        count -= read;
    }
    if(count != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
```

Comment: Also, I think calling Shutdown is necessary on the send side to ensure that the data was actually received.

Comment: @usr the send code does a `Close()`, which will suffice. `Shutdown` is handy if you want to (for example) close the *outbound* pipe while still listening on the *inbound* pipe.

Comment: Does close wait for the last byte to be acknowledged? The docs are very sparse on that issue. NetworkStream.Close does shutdown(both);close;

Comment: @usr an interesting subtlety - agreed, it isn't exactly clear

Comment: +1, although I would suggest having a "length" at the start of the actual data too, in the case that a single connection is used to send several images (not currently the case, but it could be a future enhancement).

Comment: @icabod it would also be handy just in terms of having confidence that we received all the data, rather than simply the socket broke half way through